# REST API to search multiple possible parameters

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I have an application that will have a front end that contains fields for a provider.  One of the options is to be able to search for different providers.  There can be up to 6 fields populated to search on or they can only submit one field for the search.  For example, it can search on firstName, lastName, taxId or it can just search on lastName.
Can anyone steer me in the right direction on how to do this?  I haven't been able to find any relevant tutorials for this specific problem.  Any examples or links to this type of solution would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just implement a `RestController` and specify your query params using `@RequestParam`. You can use either `Optional` as the type or specifiy `required=false` in the annotation

Comment: What about for the repository?  What method could I use being that it could be anywhere from 1-6 parameters that it looks for?

Comment: You would validate that the user supplied exactly lastName, those three fields, or any other combination you accept. Then you can add different methods in your repository for each valid combination

Answer (score -1):

isn't it become very complex for programmer to validate every possible combination what if there are 30 fields available then there will hundred's of combinations to validate. Is there any other solution for that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please answer the question in the answers section, you can comment and ask or comment about details you want or want to add to the question.